# Proving determinant of a triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Prove that if $M \in M_{n,n}(F)$ can be written in the form
>   $M=\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ O & C \end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ and $C$ are square matrices, then $\det(M)=\det(A)*\det(C)$

I am not sure the rigorous way of proving, and I see some proof goes by block matrix, which is something not yet learned about.

My idea is constructing a triangular matrix, then by cofactor expansion, we lead to a linear combination of the form of the determinant. Is that doable?

Another thing is should I separate by cases, when the matrix is invertible or when not invertible?

Comment: See Ebrahimian during office hours.

Comment: You can use the permutation definition of determinant to prove this

Comment: @Coriolanus not yet learned... So I would think proof by induction then.